# Lag function in Time series using R tool in Alteryx not working

Tags: r, time-series, alteryx

I am trying to use 'Lag' function in R tool of Alteryx.  I have copied my R code from R studio to R tool in Alteryx. After I create the first time-series using TS function, I want another series to be a lag series of the previous one.  I tried 'lag' function from 'stats' package and 'quantmode' package in Alteryx but none of them worked (working well in R studio). When I see the output data, the second series is not lagged, it is on the same level as the first one. Has anyone tried using LAG in R tool of Alteryx? Please suggest.